# Can we have and manage QlikView User in Sql and handel their access to special sheet?

Tags: sql, security, active-directory, dashboard, qlikview

I want to have and manage all QlikView user in SQL instead of having them in active directory. I do not want to create one by one in qlikview Is there any way to use all user in sql and connect them in qlikview and manage access to sheet there ?

Answer (score 0):

Haven't done it myself but think that these things are achieved via `Directory Service Connectors`/`Directory Service Providers` (`DSP`)

This [document](https://community.qlik.com/cyjdu72974/attachments/cyjdu72974/qlikview-app-development/317280/1/SettingUpConfigurableODBCDSP.docx) (`docx`) explains how to setup `DSP` with `MS SQL`, `Excel` or `Oracle`

Comment: Additionally to what Stefan wrote I think that small business edition handled only Active Directory so please check first is it possible with your license (you can always open ticket in qlikview for that). Alternative way is also that users on your server will act as a "local active directory" so probably some powershell script could take data from sql and manage users (in Azure there is "automate" for powershell + sql scripts)